# Retrieve MD5 of file at the time of check-in in TFS

Tags: php, visual-studio-2012, tfs, md5

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with TFS. I am writing a tool that checks a separate database with tf history retrieved from TFS. However, I can only get an MD5 from the current file I have stored locally, this gives me inaccurate results if I am searching the database for the file but related to an earlier changeset. Is there a way to retrieve the MD5 of the file at the time of check-in?

I am writing a script in PHP (5.3) to do all this and I know there is md5_file(filename) or you can do md5(file_get_contents(filename)) but that is only for the locally saved file.

***EDIT: I found a workaround, when I use tf history and get all the changesets for a file I also use tf get filename.txt;changeset# and then get the md5 as I go. I'm not sure if there is a more effective way but this works for now.

Answer (score 2):

I know how to achieve this by TFS API. If you query for the pending changes in the workspace using GetPendingChanges() (or QueryPendingSets() if you don’t want all of the pending changes for the workspace), you’ll get an array of PendingChange objects.  The PendingChange object has quite a few properties.  Two of those properties are **[HashValue](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.pendingchange.hashvalue.aspx)** and **[UploadHashValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.pendingchange.hashvalue.aspx)**.   `PendingChange.HashValue` property which gets the *MD5 HashValue* for the contents of the pending change.

The HashValue property is the **MD5 hash of the content of the version** against which the change was pended.  This value will be different from the MD5 hash of the file on disk, which you will need to compute yourself using **MD5CryptoServiceProvider**.

More details please refer this blog: [TFS API: Determining if an edited file has changed](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2007/08/16/tfs-api-determining-if-an-edited-file-has-changed/)

Comment: Thank you! I will look at this in detail, but after reading the post initially it appears it is not something I can utilize in my php script. Is there a command or option in tf history I can use to show the md5 for that changeset of the file?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no this kind of *tf command* will directly return  corresponding MD5 for a file with specific changeset. Using MD5 is just for the comparison of special cases. In TFS, if you want to get specific version of a file, you just need to know the changeset version of that file and get it with that changeset. You workaround seems good for your need. By the way, why you want to get MD5 of that file in your case? Couldn't you directly store corresponding  changeset of all versions for a file?

Comment: i'm updating a tool at work, in a database the file is sometimes (rarely) not stored with an associated changeset. The tool did a search using the MD5 but it was the MD5 of the file at the time of execution of the tools so this returned inaccurate results sometimes.